# Nodejs check for authentification before each routes rendering

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware

I'm using sessions and cookies to authenticate the users. I would like to check for users having a cookie and if so i will set the sessions variables.
So basicly what i do is :

1. Check if sessions variables exist
2. If not, check if user has cookie
3. If he has a cookie, I compare the value in my database.
4. If everything's ok, I set up the session.

Now i'd like to have that process into a module so i don't have to paste that code into each routes of my site.

Let's say I've put all that code in a middleware route located at `routes/middleware/check_auth.js`.

How do I export this module so I can check in my route page if the user has auth or not, something like :

```
//routes/index.js
var check_auth = require('./middleware/check_auth');
module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/', check_auth, function(req, res){
        if(variable_from_check_auth == true){
               res.render('index_with_auth');
            }else{
               res.render('index_without_auth');
            }
    });
};
```

Btw, I'm not sure if it's the right way to do or if I simply have to :

1. Call the module on each routes.
2. Check for some sessions variables before rendering.

If someone could help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can just export your middleware as simple as this(assuming you are using express session handler and cookie parser):

```
var userModel = require('./user');
module.exports = function check_auth(res, req, next) {
    if (!res.session) {
        req.send(401);
        return;
    }

    userModel.isAuthenticated(req.session.id, function (result) {
        if (!result) {
            req.send(401);
            return;
        });

        next();
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Farid, thank you for your answer. Yes I use session and cookieParser. Your answer is a bit complicated for me since I'm not using any usermodel. Also, I don't want to send 401 status. I updated my question which was not very well writed, maybe you could get me the right answer now. Ty